# Histogram of grouped data in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, histogram, rdd

I have data consisting of a date-time, IDs, and velocity, and I'm hoping to get histogram data (start/end points and counts) of velocity for each ID using PySpark. Sample data:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("2023-06-01 07:09:17", "abc", 4.5),
        ("2023-06-01 07:09:18", "abc", 9.1),
        ("2023-06-01 07:09:19", "abc", 3.2),
        ("2023-06-01 07:10:06", "ddc", 5.1),
        ("2023-06-01 07:09:07", "ddc", 3.6),
        ("2023-06-01 07:09:08", "ddc", 2.6)
    ],
    ["date_time", "id", "velocity"]
)
```

I'm not too picky about how the output is formatted. Initially I was histograms using Spark's `rdd.histogram(bins)` function, but this was over all the velocity values (with no grouping). This code was:

```py
df.filter(col("velocity").isNotNull()).rdd.histogram(list(range(0, 100, 1)))
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this for grouped data. I've tried these two things:

```py
# This throws an error: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'rdd'
df.filter(col("velocity").isNotNull()).groupBy("id").rdd.histogram(list(range(0, 100, 1)))

# This throws a much longer error, but ends with: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
# I think this has to do with the rdd.groupBy method
df.filter(col("velocity").isNotNull()).rdd.groupBy("id").histogram(list(range(0, 100, 1)))

# This throws a long error, with this TypeError: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
df.filter(col("velocity").isNotNull()).select("id", "velocity").rdd.groupByKey().histogram(list(range(0, 100, 1)))
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with (start/end points and counts) ?  I cannot understand the desired X and Y for your histogram.

Comment: I envision output looking like two lists, one with left/right limits for each bin (e.g., [0, 1, 2, 3] outlines 3 bins, the first closed on 0 and open on 1, the second closed on 1 and open on 2, the third closed on 2 and open on 3.); second list is the count that is associated with each bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by `id` and simply count the number of `velocity` values that falls in all the intervals that you are interested in. It would go as follows:

```py
result = df.filter(col("velocity").isNotNull())\
           .groupBy("id")\
           .agg( *[sum(
               when((col("velocity") >= i) & (col("velocity") < (i+1)), 1)
                   .otherwise(0)
           ).alias(f"between_{i}_{i+1}") for i in range(10)])

result.show()
```

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| id|between_0_1|between_1_2|between_2_3|between_3_4|between_4_5|between_5_6|between_6_7|between_7_8|between_8_9|between_9_10|
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|abc|          0|          0|          0|          1|          1|          0|          0|          0|          0|           1|
|ddc|          0|          0|          1|          1|          0|          1|          0|          0|          0|           0|
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

And if you prefer a simple array:

```py
result\
    .select("id", array(
        [col(f"between_{i}_{i+1}") for i in range(10)]
    ).alias("histogram") )\
    .show(truncate = False)
```

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |histogram                     |
+---+------------------------------+
|abc|[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]|
|ddc|[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+---+------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I will add that for this to work properly, you have to use the pyspark.sql function called `sum` (`from pyspark.sql import functions as F` then call `F.sum()`).